# remove line containing date not in the filename_date

Tags: awk, sed

I have a folder full of monthly data files, containing the month of interest.

> ie: data_06.csv

In each file I have average hourly values, but because of timezone offsetting in the query that generated these datasets each data_month file contains one hourly value from the previous month only if that month is one that experiences daylight savings. Point being, not every file in the folder has such an issue.

I am wanting a script that scrolls through a folder and removes a line if it starts with a month that is not in the title.

Here is a slice of some data from a file named data_06.csv:

```
> 05-31-23  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
> 06-01-00  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
> 06-01-01  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
> 06-01-02  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
```

It would be straightforward if there was only one group of dates in each file, as I would just delete the first record, but there are hourly values for each month for multiple stations. In other words, after the above dataset for the Airport finishes, this starts:

```
05-31-23    AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-00    AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-01    AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-02    AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-03    AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
```

**FOLLOW UP:**

The below solution is partly doing the job, all I need now is to figure out how to add the 1st line (the header) of every file into the newfile.

Here is my attempt that is not working...

```
NR == 1{print > (FILENAME ".new")};
{ month = FILENAME; gsub("[^0-9]","", month) }
$1 == month {print >> (FILENAME ".new")}
```

I can get the 1st line to print to stout, but not to a file that I then print (append) onto. Thanks for the final help!

Comment: I've updated my answer to print the header. You basically had it, it's just that you want to use `FNR` instead of `NR`.  `FNR` is the record number within the current file, so it is reset to one for each file.  `NR` is the current record number overall including all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be one approach. Pull the month out of the file name using the awk built-in variable `FILENAME`. Then compare the month to the first field of the line, using `-` as the field separator. If they're the same, print the line to a new file with the same name adding `.new` as a suffix. That way you can process multiple files in one command and have ".new" versions of each when you're done.

**EDIT:** Include header of each file in output.

**EDIT 2:** Move setting of FS to begin block as suggested in comment.

```
$ cat data.awk
BEGIN { FS = "-" }
FNR == 1 { print > (FILENAME ".new"); next }
{ month = substr(FILENAME,6,2) }
$1 == month { print > (FILENAME ".new") }

$ cat data_06.csv
Data 06 header
05-31-23  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
06-01-00  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
06-01-01  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
06-01-02  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
05-31-23  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-00  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-01  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-02  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-03  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0

$ cat data_07.csv
Data 07 header
06-31-23  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
06-01-00  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
07-01-01  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
07-01-02  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
05-31-23  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-00  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
07-01-01  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
07-01-02  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
07-01-03  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0

$ awk -f data.awk data_*.csv

$ ls *.new
data_06.csv.new     data_07.csv.new

$ cat data_06.csv.new
Data 06 header
06-01-00  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
06-01-01  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
06-01-02  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
06-01-00  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-01  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-02  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
06-01-03  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0

$ cat data_07.csv.new
Data 07 header
07-01-01  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
07-01-02  Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   1   0.0
07-01-01  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
07-01-02  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
07-01-03  AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   0.0
```

Comment: Thanks jas, I really like the approach: compact and able to run on multiple files...I am curious about the built in FILENAME variable...does it basically just look at the filename and cast it as a string variable, which is then called "month" given some parameter (gsub, etc.)? I will do some reading up on it but in case you had another explanation since you did suggest using it. Thanks again!

Comment: I went to up vote your answer but I do not have the required 15 reputation, sorry :(

Comment: Ok, this works great; however, it does not copy over the header info. I have one line of column titles and because the first field isn't matched it does not get copied to new file. Is there an approach to remove the line containing the month that is not the same as the title month, or is there a way to skip the first line of each file?

Comment: I've updated the question with what I have in an attempt to print the 1st line, then do the solution you proposed

Comment: You're very welcome, @geokrowding. I've updated the answer to include the header. `FILENAME` is a string variable containing the file name. I assigned it to a variable called `month`, and then I used the `gsub` function to substitute all non-digit characters in `month` with the empty string, leaving only the two digits.  In the edited version I changed it to simply assign `month` a substring of `FILENAME`, starting at (1-based) position 6 for a length of 2. That seems more straightforward, but I am assuming all your file names are of the form `data_MM...` where `MM` are the month digits.

Comment: If you're saving your script in an .awk file, I would recommend you add `BEGIN {FS="-"}`. That way all your code is in one place, and you don't have to remember to use the `-F-` option

Comment: +1 **@jas** & @glenn jackman - you guys are awesome, thanks! What does the "; next" do. Also, I fibbed a bit and have a folder full of files with varying lengths containing a 2-digit month value. In that case, I think the gsub worked better (length agnostic), however, the "starting at position 6 for a length of 2 approach add another tool to my belt, and provides another way of doing what I've asked. Also, would you mind giving me some reputation props somehow, that way I can up vote your great answers/solutions, please and thank you! Cheers :)

Comment: Hi, @geokrowding, the `next` statement says to stop processing the current record and immediately read the next line of the file. In other words, after the `next` it won't go on to the actions below. It's probably not necessary here, but without it if somehow the header started with "06-" (for month 06) it would get printed twice!  One way you can both give and get a few rep points for yourself is to "accept" an answer that solves your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: Excellent explanations all around, and I do appreciate a "best practices" approach to such commands as I am new and trying to get into good habits. I like the bolded edits you put as well, and will try to incorporate that sort of marking up when I go about edits in the future. :) Case closed...